# DBT docker: Docs Served but Not Accessible via Browser

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dbt

I've  try to use dbt on docker with the configuration from [official docker](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/blob/main/docker/Dockerfile) and with my `docker-compose.yaml` and `profiles.yml` below. The code is from [this course](https://github.com/DataTalksClub/data-engineering-zoomcamp/tree/main/week_4_analytics_engineering/docker_setup).

After, `docker compose build` and `dbt project init` every others command (e.g., `dbt debug`, `dbt run`, `dbt docs generate`) is working fine. But `dbt docs serve` is logging as served but not accessible.

I've try to delete `network_mode: host` line from `docker-compose.yaml` as suggested from the course FAQ. However, the docs serve still not served.

- `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3'
  services:
    <projectName>:
      build:
        context: .
        target: dbt-bigquery
      image: dbt/bigquery
      volumes:
        - .:/usr/app
        - ~/.dbt/:/root/.dbt/
        - <path to gg cred key>
      network_mode: host
```

- `profiles.yml`

```
bq-dbt-workshop:
  outputs:
    dev:
      dataset: <bigquery-dataset>
      fixed_retries: 1
      keyfile: <path to gg cred key>
      location: asia-southeast1
      method: service-account
      priority: interactive
      project: <gcp-project-id>
      threads: 4
      timeout_seconds: 300
      type: bigquery
  target: dev
```

- `dbt docs serve` log

```
14:36:04  Running with dbt=1.0.8
14:36:04  Serving docs at 0.0.0.0:8080
14:36:04  To access from your browser, navigate to:  http://localhost:8080
14:36:04
14:36:04
14:36:04  Press Ctrl+C to exit.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the command `docs generate && docs serve`?

Comment: @AleixCC Hello, I've tried `dbt docs generate && dbt docs serve` but the result is the same as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

So, according to [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports):

> `docker-compose run` ignores `ports` unless you include `--service-ports`.

---

Therefore you either need to provide `--publish` or `-p` when calling `docker compose run` (even if the ports are already defined in your docker compose file) or pass the `--service-ports` flag.

Comment: @Kodi any luck ? I am running into same issue, and I tried to pass in port: 8080 into .yml file as well

Answer (score 0):

You probably needs to expose the port `8080` (the default port that `dbt docs serve` serves on, you can change it with `--ports`) from Docker by replacing the `network_mode: host` with a `ports:` list in your docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
  services:
    <projectName>:
      build:
        context: .
        target: dbt-bigquery
      image: dbt/bigquery
      volumes:
        - .:/usr/app
        - ~/.dbt/:/root/.dbt/
        - <path to gg cred key>
      ports:
        - "8080:8080"
```