# docker-compose with multiple options to enable dbt's serve docs functionality

Tags: docker, dbt

I am trying to generate/access documentation for dbt via this guide: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/commands/cmd-docs. The issue is I am getting a 'This Site Cant Be Reached'. So I am referencing this post [DBT docker: Docs Served but Not Accessible via Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72677860/dbt-docker-docs-served-but-not-accessible-via-browser) - which notes to add --publish to my docker-compose. Currently I have a makefile with the line below:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml
```

I would think to change it to the below but does not seem to work.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -p
```

as I get the error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "-p": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

As well, I tried to edit the docker-compose.yml file to include the below:

```
version: '3.9'
services:

localdev:
    build: .
    image: localdev:latest
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "8080"
        - "8080:8080
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    environment:
        - ENV=my-env
        - ADD_PATH=/bin/docker
    volumes:
        - $LOCAL_REPO_DIR:/usr/app/code
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
        - /usr/local/bin:/bin/docker:ro
    command: /usr/app/entrypoint.sh
```

While this allowed me to spin up the container, I was still not able to access to webpage locally.

Comment: What does docker-compose.yml look like?

Comment: @tconbeer - thx for the thought, but I tried both of the ports you advised on and I I still get "this site can't be reached"

Comment: what about just `docker-compose up`, with no arguments, since the file is in your cwd?

Comment: I changed my makefile for us to have:

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml 
 docker compose up run -p 8080:8080

Answer (score 1):

`dbt docs serve` by default serves on port 8080. If you want the `localdev` container's port 8080 to be accessible at 8080 on the host machine, you need:

```yaml
ports:
    - "8080:8080"
```

You should *only* list port 8080 once in this list; if you list it alone, without a host port:

```yaml
ports:
    - 8080
```

Docker will expose it on a *random* port on the host.